# Booting from USB: initramfs, medium container

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Apologies for the general title, but I don‘t know how more succinctly I can express the issue.

I have an HP Spectre 13-v000 laptop. It has Windows 10 installed. I want to turn it into a Linux laptop.

I followed the instructions in “installing Ubuntu desktop” (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) and “create a bootable usb stick on windows”(https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview).

I prepared the usb stick (with Ubuntu 20.04), plugged in and got an: “unable to find a medium container a live file system”.

I googled, and it was suggested to change usb-port, use a usb-hub or disable usb 3. The point is that this laptop only has usb-c ports (for normal usb there is the adapter from hp). I tried all ports to no avail. I looked around in the BIOS settings, but I don’t see any ‘disable usb3’ (as it should, as there are only usb-c’s).

I googled deeper, and I found these possibilities:

Enable legacy support
Disable secure boot
Change order of uefi boot (priorities usb)
Change order of legacy boot (priorities usb)
I tried the first 3 possibilities to no avail.

I get a screen with:

```
[0.528902] initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
stein: Invalid argument
Unable to find a live medium containing a live file system
Attempt interactive NetBoot from a URL?
yes no (default yes):_
```

I am a newbie, so maybe I misunderstood something when googling: I do not want a dual system. This is a laptop which I am not using anymore. I want to learn Linux commands, and thought to completely wipe out the old Windows OS from it.

Should I change the above mentioned BIOS settings? What should I do? I don’t have any attachments to Ubuntu nor Ubuntu 20.04: if I have to completely change approach that’s fine. I just want a Linux-based computer.

P.S.: I had already posted this question on askubuntu, but as of the time of writing nobody replied.

Comment: You have a typo in there. The error actually reads "unable to find a live medium containing a live file system". The "Decoding failed" is more interesting. It tells you that the initramfs was not unpacked. This usually happens with broken USB drive or if the installation image has not been completely transferred (the latter happens if you remove the USB drive too early).

Comment: Is the SATA mode set to (Intel) RST instead of AHCI? Can you change the setting in your BIOS?

Comment: @Hermann Thank you for the typo. About the USB: it's not corrupted (when I use on my othe computer, there are no issues). I've always left the stick attached during (attempted) booting.

Comment: I double checked. I scanned the USB stick using Windows' Error checking: no error found

Comment: @Freddy I looked into the BIOS settings: I didn't find an option to change the SATA mode. On the web I found that for relatively recent hp notebooks, such an option is not left to the user, and that it is by default to one of the 2 enabled.

Comment: Was other system you tested flash drive on also UEFI? Rufus creates either UEFI/gpt for UEFI or CSM/MBR for BIOS boot of installer. And how you boot install medium is then how it installs. Only use UEFI. HP Spectre x360 Disable Optane (should use gpt to boot installer in UEFI mode)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204386/windows-10-wont-boot-after-dual-boot-installation-optane-volume [Guide] Install Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Spectre x360 13" 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414086 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2422113

Comment: If you're lucky `F10` followed by `A` works for the advanced settings menu (seen [here](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-REQUEST-HP-15-ay000-Notebook-PC-series-BIOS-Unlock) for a different model).

Comment: I had a similar issue when trying to install Ubuntu 21.04 on a barebones PC, and the manufacturer suggested turning off IOMMU in the BIOS.  That fixed the issue for me.